# How to use scss @use in React scss modules

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to create a globally accessible colors master file for my project, but keep getting a `SassError: Invalid CSS after... expected expression` error. My file structure looks like:

```
|src
    |components
    |         |Skillset
    |                 |Skillset.js
    |                 |Skillset.module.scss
    |_colors.scss
```

In my `_colors.scss` file, I have `$darkPurple: #3B3B4F;` at the top.

In my `Skillset.module.scss` file, I have it written as:

```
@use "src/colors";

.skillsetContent {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: colors.$darkPurple; //<--- this is where I'm using the variable
    padding: 0 140px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Yet I'm getting the SassError in the console.

I was planning to use the `@import` command initially, but the Sass website suggests against that now and requests you use `@use` now, but I can't seem to get it to work. I have both node-scss and node-sass installed in the project as well.

Anything obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

node-sass won't support @use. To support @use you need to use dart-scss.

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```